# How to handle mouse wheel stop in JQuery for smooth scrolling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, mousewheel, smooth-scrolling

I have problem. I making site with animation. I using mouse wheel steps data for moving div's with css. In firefox all working fine.

But Chrome working not good. On chrome minimal step is 100px and movements very fragmentary. And i want to get sum from scrolling series for moving blocks with animation.

For example, user making 3 nonstop scrolls (one step is 100px), jquery getting variable=300px and I can apply animation function. How i can handle stopping events between scrolling series?

Different way - is making for example 10 steps from 100px variable and after every step i can change css variable. But i havent any ideas about it. Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look on this amazing project : http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4 Permit smooth scrolling on every browser, mobile included.

Comment: Would be easyer for us to see what's the problem if you could get us the code in fiddle.